# How to use method calls within rjust?

Tags: ruby

As part of my ruby learning, I would like to call `size` method within `rjust` passing it as first parameter.  Not sure how to do it.

For e.g.

```
2.to_s(2) #=> returns "10"
```

Now, I would like to use `rjust` on `10` passing `:size + 5` as first argument to get `*****10`

```
2.to_s(2).rjust(how_to_get_size_of_10_and_add_5, "*") #=> dont know how to.
```

Unsuccessfully, tried the below:

```
2.to_s(2).tap{|s| rjust(s.size+5,"*")} #=> ...undefined method `rjust' for main:Object
2.to_s(2).rjust(send(:size)+5,"*") #=> ... undefined method `size' for main:Object
```

I am trying to understand how to refer and exercise a method on a part of chain of method calls. In my example I am trying to call `rjust` on `2.to_s(2)` and within rjust refer the `size` of `2.to_s(2)`.  Sorry if my writing is clumsy

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. What is "size of previous outcome"?

Comment: Seems to me that you just want to prepend 5 asterisks to the string? `rjust` is a wrong tool for that.

Comment: What you are trying to do is right-justify the string to a lenght of `size + 5`. This is equivalent to simply prepending five `*`, so you can just do `"*****#{2.to_s(2)}"` maybe even `('*' * 5) + 2.to_s(2)`

Comment: `"*****%b" % 2` is another option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you are doing this indirectly, but perhaps what you tried to do is:

```
2.to_s(2).tap{|s| break s.rjust(s.size + 5, "*")}
```

A new method is proposed in the Ruby core for situations like this, but it is not yet available. In the mean while, you have to use the combination of `tap` and `break`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `tap` here when you `break` out anyway? It just adds noise, I'd use a variable.

Comment: @p11y To avoid variable assignment outside. I am trying to show a minimal correction to the OP's code. A more straightforward way is to just add `"*" * 5`. But the OP seems to want to learn how to use `tap` in situations like this.

Comment: @p11y: because there's no `map` for a single object.

Comment: @sawa: Could you please enlighten me on why using `break` works and not using it doesnt?

Comment: @Bala `break` returns from the block, replacing `tap`'s default return value

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just don't see what kind of value the `tap` adds here. It's unidiomatic, unreadable code.

Comment: @p11y: I agree it's not very readable, but there's not much else we can use to build a one-liner.

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner? Sorry if this seems nit-picky but whats wrong with a variable i.e. `s = 2.to_s(2); s.rjust(s.size + 5, "*")`?

Comment: @p11y One-liner doesn't matter much. The point is, as I wrote, to encapsule the variable. Or in other words, to allow chaining.

Comment: @p11y to me, using a variable is less idiomatic (compared to one-liner). But in this case, it's probably better. Anyway, it's good that we have more than one way to do stuff. :)

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean now. Thanks for commenting everyone. It's just that I use `tap` when I want to call a method on an object and then return the object itself, even if the method returns something different than the original object. Here `tap` is merely used as a way of setting a local variable `s`, kind of reminds me of the Y-Combinator in FP.

Comment: @sawa out of curiosity: what is the new method proposed in Ruby Core you were speaking of?

Comment: Unreasonable breaking of control flow just worsening the readability. If insist on one-liner-one-expression, with use of currently available methods the example may be written as `2.to_s(2).each_line.map {|s| s.rjust(s.size+5,'*')}.first`. Much cleaner and straightforward solution is already mentioned use of string formatting method `String#%` or complementary `Kernel.sprintf`.

Comment: @DavidUnric `each_line` + `map` + `first` is much less readable (and also inefficient) than `tap` + `break`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put aside the reasons *why* you want to do *that*. I'll answer the direct question, "how".

If your string were a collection, it'd be a simple `map`. We can, therefore, wrap the string in the array (of one element), map and then unwrap.

```
Array(2.to_s(2)).map{|str| str.rjust(str.size + 5, '*') }.first # => "*****10"
```

Unfortunately, there's no `map` for a single object. But we can work around this by using `tap` + `break` hack.

```
2.to_s(2).tap{|str| break str.rjust(str.size + 5, '*')} # => "*****10"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think printing five stars and a number can be expressed much simper (`"*****%b" % 2` as @stefan suggested in the comments), but you can do it your way too:

```
2.to_s(2).instance_eval do
  rjust(size + 5, '*')
end
```

However, the `tap`+`break`-hack (suggested by @sawa and @sergio) is superior to this solution. It is 2-3 times faster than using `instance_eval` while `instance_eval` bypasses encapsulation by replacing `self`.

So, do not use `instance_eval` in your case except for academical interests or for code golfing :)

---

The benchmark results are:

```
tap+break      2.020000   0.000000   2.020000 (  2.017987)
instance_eval  5.380000   0.000000   5.380000 (  5.383094)
```

The benchmark script is:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 5000000
Benchmark.benchmark do |x|
  x.report("tap+break") do
    n.times do
      '10'.tap { |str| break str.rjust(str.length + 5, '*') }
    end
  end

  x.report("instance_eval") do
    n.times do
      '10'.instance_eval { rjust(length + 5, '*') }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that this also changes `self`, and is slow.

Comment: When using `instance_eval`, the block argument is redundant, just use `2.to_s(2).instance_eval { rjust(size + 5, '*') }`. Be careful, though, you're inside the receiver, bypassing encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments -- you're totally right. I was interested in *how* slow `instance_eval` really is and did a dirty benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would be:

```
'*' * 5 + 2.to_s(2)
```

This will always prepend 5 asterisks to the string.